# Extjs 4 upload success function does not react

Tags: javascript, node.js, extjs

i have a grid with an toolbar and on that toolbar an upload option is added, so the upload is alright and it works , but after the file was uploaded to the server the success function does not react.

here my upload code:

```
upload: function () {

        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Upload',
            width: 300,
            layout: 'fit',
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            bodyPadding: 5,


            items: [{
                xtype: 'form',
                bodyPadding: 10,
                frame: true,
                items: [{
                    xtype:'filefield',
                    name:'file',
                    fieldLabel: 'File',
                    buttonText: 'Select File',
                    labelWidth: 30,
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Upload',
                    handler: function(){                        
                         var form = this.up('form').getForm();

                         if(form.isValid()){
                             form.submit({  
                                 method: 'POST',     
                                 url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload',

                                 success: function (form, action) {
                                     Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your File has been uploaded.');
                                     console.log(action);
                                 },
                                 failure : function (form,action) {
                                     Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Failed to upload file.');
                                 }

                             })
                         }

                    }
                }] 
            }],

        }).show();

    },  

});
```

and the server response :

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Content-Type','application/json; charset=UTF8');

    var tmp_path = req.files.file.path;
    var newPath = __dirname + '/files/' + req.files.file.name;
    fs.rename(tmp_path, newPath, function (err){
        if (err) throw err;

    });


    var path = newPath;
    var name = req.files.file.name; 

    connection.query('SELECT name FROM audio WHERE name = ?', [name] , function(err,result) {

        if (result[0]) {
            console.log('File already exist');
            res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify());

        } else {

            connection.query('INSERT INTO audio (name, path) VALUES (?,?)', [name,path], function (err,result) {
                if (err) throw err;

                var test = {
                    success: true
                };

                res.send({success:true});
                console.log('success');
            });


        }
    });


});
```

i can provide more code if necessary, thanks in advance

Comment: are u getting any error in console? and whether that url has been hit in the backend

Comment: well in firefox with firebug i dont get anything , in chrome i get this -> Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: i get the file at the server, and the server sends the json with success:true but it´s still not working..

Comment: try with return "success" instead of res.send({success:true}); in backend.

Comment: tried it , did not work

Answer (score 1):

The error message is explicit: your response is lost due to cross-domain iframe issue.

See the [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload) explanation of how file upload form are handled: a hidden iframe is created to receive the response from the server (because, before HTML5 it was not possible to upload a file using XHR). When the iframe is loaded, Ext parses its content to read the response.

But, it is only allowed for a page to manipulate its iframes content if both are on the same domain, including the port number.

Most probably you're accessing your page at `http://localhost/`, while you're posting your form to `http://localhost:3000`. So forbidden: error, and no response for you!

Comment: The downvoters should comment what they think it wrong with this answer and not only downvote because it is not what they want to hear! IMO this answer is correct +1

Answer (score 0):

This is a Ext js bug identified by Uberdude in the Sencha Forum.

**Description of the problem :**

When you make an Ext.Ajax.request with a form containing a file input to be uploaded, or manually set the isUpload option to true, rather than doing a proper Ajax request Ext submits the form in the standard HTML way to a dynamically generated hidden . The json response body is then read out of the iframe to create a faked-up Ajax response. A problem arises if the page making the upload Ajax request has changed its document.domain property, e.g. a page at home.example.com includes resources from static.example.com which it wishes to manipulate with javascript without violating the browser's same-origin-policy, so both set their document.domain to "example.com". If home.example.com then makes an upload Ajax request to a url on the home.example.com server, the iframe into which the response is written will have its document.domain as "home.example.com". Thus when the ExtJS code within Ajax.request on the home.example.com page tries to extract the document body from the iframe, it will be blocked by the same-origin-policy and the response passed to the callback functions will incorrectly have empty responseText.

**Work Around :** 
   1. Pass the document.domain to the server when making the upload request. 
   2. In your server response, add the document.domain in your response text/html.

response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        response.write('document.domain = "' + params.__domain + '";');
        response.write(JSON.stringify({msg: 'Welcome ' + params.name}));
        response.end('');

**Detail :**

Please refer to :
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136092-Response-lost-from-upload-Ajax-request-to-iframe-if-document.domain-changed