# ExtJS 6.6.0 Enable CORS in form submit

Tags: javascript, extjs, cross-domain, php-7

How to enable Cross Domain in `ExtJS 6.6.0`

```
this.getForm().submit({
    url: REST.API_DOMAIN + REST.API_ATTACH + data.id,
    scope: this,
    success: function(form, result) {
        console.info(result);
    },
    failure: function(form, result) {
        console.info(result);
    }
});
```

Although the REST API is fully cross-domain, `ExtJS` rejects the response.

```
response headers HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 11:41:36 GMT 
Server: Apache Content-Encoding: gzip Vary: 
Accept-Encoding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS X-Frame- 
Options: ALLOW-FROM app.domain.io 
Content-Length: 1335 
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: In backend what you using as a server? e.g. nodejs, php, GoLang ...

Comment: PHP 7 with ZendFramework 3. at response headers
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 11:41:36 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://app.domain.io
Content-Length: 1335
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

to use cross domain requests you must use jsonp or  if you need it in only development process you can run chrome with --disable-web-security flag. (edit shortcut of chrome and add in target something like this:

C:\Users{your_user}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="G:\chrome")

Comment: The case is for production